# Keep caption together with table when table is in different section

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I've a requirement to format table into two columns, but keep its caption in one column.

It works generally well if I add a continuous section break between them.

The only issue is when only the table would go to the next page. Although "keep with next" is set for the caption it doesn't affect formatting and caption and table are separated to different pages (as in screenshot below), probably due to the section break (without section break there is no such problem)

Is there a solution for this problem?

Current situation: caption is in one column, table is in two columns, caption is not forced to next page together with table:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct solution to the problem, so my workaround is to not use columns.

Instead I add another table with two columns (with no visible borders), manually split my original table and place it in the new table.

Answer (score -1):

Try "Text wrapping -> Around" in Table Properties:

[image]